# Query Regarding Database Instance not proper

Tags: sql-server

Please sort out one issue regarding SQL Server instances. I have one instance of SQL Server named 'Test\Connect' and other one is 'local' by default.

So the issue is when I connect to local and Test\Connect instances, the databases seen are the same. I am not able to see the databases which I have created in my instance Test\Connect.

But when I connect through IP\Connect (IP address of Test and same instance name) then I can see the databases.

Please help me out and let me know the process how we can sort this out.

Comment: Are you sure that Test resolves to the IP address you expect?